# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<<anonymous type>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'

Tags: c#, linq, generics

my code supposed to check two conditions and return the values but when i try to return **q** this error shows up

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<< anonymous type: string Name, string File>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List< string>

and i tried everything but nothing worked also don't know to set `List<string>` or set it as `List<EF_Model.PDF>` ,PDF is a DTO in my model

this is my code

```
  internal List<string> Customers_File(int _id)
    {
        using (var Context = new EF_Model.CoolerEntities())
        {
            var q = from c in Context.Customers
                    where c.Id == _id &&
                    c.Ref_PDF != null
                    select new { c.PDF.Name, c.PDF.File };
            return q.ToList();
        }
    }
```

Comment: And what part of the error message that tells you exactly what's wrong didn't you understand?

Comment: You could use : select new string[] { c.PDF.Name, c.PDF.File };

Comment: So what do you want to *actually* return from your method - a list of strings or a list of PDF Name & file?

Comment: I can see what fields you have, and I know you want it to "just work" - but its not clear what you want to do!

Comment: i want to get those 2 values from DB @Jamiec

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to convert the anonymous object into a string representation.(Note I'm using C# 6.0 feature - string interpolation, you can replace it with string.Format in the previous versions.
Example:

```
return q.Select(x=>$"Name = {x.PDF.Name} File = {c.PDF.File}").ToList();
```

Comment: Oh! You *have* to turn it into an explicit string! Interesting

Answer (score 1):

You need to define an object with your to properties

```
public class PdfInfo
{
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public string File{get;set;}
}
```

Return a list of them from your method

```
internal List<PdfInfo> Customers_File(int _id)
```

And finally project to those, in place of an anonymous object:

```
....
select new PdfInfo() { Name=c.PDF.Name, File = c.PDF.File };
```

Comment: got this error >Cannot initialize type 'PDF' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'      in  here `{ Name=c.PDF.Name, File = c.PDF.File };`

Answer (score 0):

You have declared your return type as string but are returning an a list of anonymous  objects with two properties. That won't work. If you want to return a string you need to create a single string per list item. If you want to return object change your return type

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you have defined `Customers_File` as returning a list of strings. However, the list `q` that you return doesn't fit that description.

In your query, when you do

```
select new { c.PDF.Name, c.PDF.File };
```

..you are making an [Anonymous Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/bb397696(v=vs.100).aspx), and storing it in the collection `q`. This type has two fields and is clearly **not** a `string`.

Some possible solutions are:

- Change your method to have return type `List<object>` instead of `List<string>` (not recommended).
- Make your object into a string via some form of serialization (JSON or XML).
- Create a class or struct for this data and change the return type of your method to `List<dataClass>`

Comment: Changing to List<object> isn't a good idea. How do you want to use it later if it's anonymous type?

Comment: Well no, the best solution would be to not use the anonymous type in the first place. However, `List<object>` is still a possible solution.

Comment: For me it's not a solution but a way to make your project buildable ;)